# GeoDjango: How to create a geometry object from a bounding box?

Tags: django, geodjango

I am intercepting a query parameter of bounding box ex. `?bbox=160.6,-55.95,-170,-25.89` in my GeoDjango application to filter my queryset of entries that intersects with the bbox. I want to know if how can I create an geometry object from the bbox or a list of the bbox object `[160.6,-55.95,-170,-25.89]`.

```
bbox = GEOSGeometry('BBOX [160.6,-55.95,-170,-25.89]')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code. It is already implemented in geos.

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Polygon

my_bbox_polygon = Polygon.from_bbox([160.6,-55.95,-170,-25.89]) # [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]
```

You can check out the documentation for Polygon [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/geos/)